# Creating A Level List In Java

Tags: java, android, andengine

In andengine i am trying to have a levels menu that shows different level icons for each level.

Basically a list of levels with there icons and text over them saying which level it is.

I would like to know how would i go about placing a icon at each specific spot on the scene and then starting a new row when it gets to the end of the scenes view at the current time.

Here is what i am working with so far.

```
    final int COLUMNS = 5;
final int ROWS = 3;
final int PADDING = 5;

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= ROWS; i++){
for(int o = 1; o <= COLUMNS; o++){
     if(x > cameraWidth - tileWidth) break;

    Sprite tile = new Sprite(x * o, y * i, ...);

    x += tile.getWidth() + PADDING;
}
y += tile.getHeight() + PADDING
}
```

Could anyone give me further assistance with this?
I would like my level list to appear as this one..
[image]

Comment: Have you seen this post http://www.andengine.org/forums/post31409.html#p31409

Comment: Hey thanks alot for that! I believe that answers my question!